# Java bulb switch problem

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array list containing 5 bulbs. I can iterate throuh them like this

```
for(Bulb bul : list){
    System.out.println(bul.id);
}
```

No a bulb is switched off/on. The effect is that its neighbourg bulbs a switch too.

My problem is that when the last or 4th bulb are switched I need to determine its neighbours. Since I have 5 bulbs this would work.

```
int bulbIdClicked = 3;

if(bul.id == (bulbIdClicked + 1)%5)

if(bul.id == (bulbIdClicked - 1)%5)
```

For 3 it would give me 2 and 4 as neighbours. But when 4 is switched it gives me 3 and 0 ans neighbours where 0 should be 5.

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bulb ID ranging from 0 to 4, the best way to get the next and previous IDs is to use:

```
next = (id + 1) % 5
prev = (id + 4) % 5
```

This is language-agnostic since not all languages treat modulus operators on negative numbers the same. You can see that stepping forward 4 from 4 (for example) gives you: 0, 1, 2, 3 which is the same as a step backwards.

However. modulus really only works on zero-based values. Since you have one-based values, you can subtract one first, do the relevant addition/modulo, then add one again.

```
next = ((id - 1) + 1) % 5 + 1
prev = ((id - 1) + 4) % 5 + 1
```

These simplify down to:

```
next = id % 5 + 1
prev = (id + 3) % 5 + 1
```

Using those formula, you get:

```
id  next  prev
--  ----  ----
 1    2     5
 2    3     1
 3    4     2
 4    5     3
 5    1     4
```

as expected.

That's about as optimised as you're likely to get without a lookup table. You can use the same approach for any roll-over size (not just 5), you just have to change the modulo and what you add.

If the indexes range from 1 to `N`, its:

```
next = id % [N] + 1
prev = (id + [N-2]) % [N] + 1
```

where the figures inside `[]` are constant based on the number of indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If it should go from `0` to `5` you should use `%6`

Comment: Then you should use `%5` but lower your index with `1` since your list is zero-based (0-4).

Answer (score 0):

the array index starts from 0, so if you have 5 elements, then they are in position 0,1,2,3,4..

Answer (score 0):

By using 0..4 as your bulb IDs instead of 1..5. This is in fact the main reason why programmers prefer zero-based counting: it simplifies indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this is the last bulb. The last bulb will have only the left neighbor

```
if(bul.id == numBulbs)
{
   //Check only left side
   if(bul.id == (bulbIdClicked - 1)%5)
   ...
}
```

You have do the same for the first bulb

```
if(bul.id == 0)
{
   //Check only right side
   if(bul.id == (bulbIdClicked + 1)%5)
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to navigate a List backwards and forwards, use [`ListIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) (available through the `list.listIterator()` or `list.listIterator(index)` methods. Here's some sample code:

```
List<Bulb> bulbs = new ArrayList<Bulb>();
int amount = 500;
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){bulbs.add(new Bulb());}
// which one to switch off
int offset = new Random().nextInt(amount);
ListIterator<Bulb> li = bulbs.listIterator(offset);
li.next().switchOff();
if(li.hasNext()){
    li.next().switchOff();
    // go back to selected offset
    li.previous();
}
if(li.hasPrevious()){
    li.previous().switchOff();
}
```